# Wordpress permanent link thai language issue

Tags: wordpress, thai

Some characters are removed when editting permanent link.

Example "สวัสดีครับ" to "สวสดครบ"

problem found on Wordpress version 6.4.1

Please help.

Note: I tested on Wordpress version 4.5 it work fine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can test using the [sanitize_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) function to see if it is changing your text. WordPress automatically uses `sanitize_title` to sanitize the permalink into a *slug, which can be used in URLs.* The original string might not be compatible with a URL string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress 5.0+ A new editing experience for WordPress is in the works, code name Gutenberg, Gutenberg is the WordPress default editor, replacing the previous classic editor. it has a bug with thai permanent link.

I fixed it by installed Classic Editor Plugin maintained by the WordPress team that restores the previous ("classic") WordPress editor and the "Edit Post" screen